# Trying to access a database in docker containers and php

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

So I have the following docker-compose file and Dockerfile for php which I am using. These files are in a folder called cca4 and my php files are in a subdirectory of this called src. I am trying to access my mysql database that I am creating however I cannot select anything from it or insert anything. No matter what I do the queries will not work. Any idea on what is wrong? When I go into phpmyadmin I can see that my database is there however it is just not updating or being selected from. I am using nginx as the web server and php-fpm to communicate. I am doing this all from a Linux VM on GCP (Google Cloud Platform) so could be an issue with that maybe too. My php just cannot seem to pick up that there are any tables in the db or rows even after inserting them into phpmyadmin

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:latest
     volumes:
       - database:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: MyDBRoot123
       MYSQL_DATABASE: assignment_four_data
       MYSQL_USER: php
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: php
     container_name: db
     networks:
       - mynet

   myphp:
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
     depends_on:
       - db
     expose:
       - 9000
     restart: always
     volumes:
       - $PWD/src:/var/www/html
     container_name: myphp
     networks:
       - mynet
  
   mynginx:
     depends_on:
       - myphp
     image: nginx:latest
     ports:
       - "8080:80"
     restart: always
     volumes:
       - $PWD/src:/var/www/html
       - $PWD/src/nginx.ini:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
     container_name: mynginx
     networks:
       - mynet

   phpMyAdmin:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: phpmyadmin:latest
     restart: always
     environment:
       PMA_HOST: mysql
     ports:
       - "8082:80"
     container_name: phpMyAdmin
     networks:
       - mynet

volumes:
    database: {}
networks:
    mynet:
       driver: bridge
```

Here is the dockerfile.

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN pecl install igbinary \
    && pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis \
    && echo "extension=redis.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/redis.ini
```

my php code.

```
<?php
   $servername = "db";
   $username = "php";
   $password = "php";
   $databse = "assignment_four_data";
   // Create connection
   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
   if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Users';
   $result = $mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   if (!$result) {
      printf("false");
   }
   printf("Selected returned %d rows. \n", mysqli_num_rows($result));
?>
```

The error I keep receiving in my db.php file

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in /var/www/html/db.php on line 18
```

Selected returned 0 rows

Is this a docker problem or a mysqli problem? My database is definitely there in phpmyadmin but I just can't get my db.php to communicate with it. Since the mysqli_query is returning false then my query obviously isn't able to work correctly with the mysql database. Even after creating tables and inserting values in phpmyadmin it still cannot detect anything.
[image]

Comment: You have a typo in `$mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` it should be `mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` Please fix and re-try.

Comment: Hey sorry yeah that was just a mistake on here. The issue is though that I cannot seem to connect to my mysql database and my query keeps returning false. It seems like it cannot pick up that a table exists or there are any values.